# Error after creating new, empty activity

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

This error is shown by Gradle of my new empty activity, right after i create it... Afterwards, android studio is not working properly. I may have deleted something out of a java folder, but i have reinstalled java, java sdk studio and even android studio and it still shows the same thing

> Error:Cannot find JAR 'kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.1-M02.jar' required by module 'gradle-script-kotlin' using classpath or distribution directory `'C:\Users\Name\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3-all\55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9\gradle-3.3'`

Comment: You can delete everything in `C:\Users\Name\.gradle\wrapper\dists`... It should re-download them

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped.

Answer (score -2):

app build.gradle signingConfigs delete debug mode